# Kernel - Measuring the rate of timer interrupts

Tags: linux-kernel, cpu

I am working on optimizing kernels of my boxes for telephony, which involves (among other things) adjusting the HZ rate and the preemption model.

Initially the kernel was compiled with the default 250 HZ and Voluntary preemption, and the [cyclictest](https://rt.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Cyclictest) is currently showing a maximum latency of **5859**, which is fine, but not optimal. Ideally, I'd like to have it under 3000, and that's why I decided to dig deeper.

The confusing thing is, however, in trying to get the actual timer interrupt frequency: when I do

```
cat /proc/interrupts | grep LOC ; sleep 10; cat /proc/interrupts | grep LOC
```

I get

```
LOC:        212        370         92         81   Local timer interrupts
LOC:        212        370         92         81   Local timer interrupts
```

And so my values don't change (I believe the second row should be incremented by 250).

Also, when I try to measure it as described [here](http://www.advenage.com/topics/linux-timer-interrupt-frequency.php), I get

```
kernel timer interrupt frequency is approx. 2518 Hz
```

Any ideas on how to calculate it properly?

Maybe any other suggestions on kernel optimization for voice (RTC/SLAB/IO Scheduler)?

**Update:** Adding

```
CONFIG_HZ_1000=y
CONFIG_HZ=1000
CONFIG_PREEMPT_RCU=y
CONFIG_PREEMPT_NOTIFIERS=y
CONFIG_PREEMPT=y
CONFIG_PREEMPT_COUNT=y
CONFIG_DEBUG_PREEMPT=y
```

has decreased my latency to

```
T: 0 ( 4628) P:80 I:10000 C:   4059 Min:     13 Act:   33 Avg:   69 Max:
```

**3634**

I am still looking for ways to improve it though...

Comment: Did you have a look on the cstate side ? It seems you cpu0 and cpu1 are working and cpu2 and cpu3 are sleeping. The latency to switch from a deep cstate to active is a source of big latency.